# SilverStripe 3.1+ Site will not output Page.ss template content

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, web-hosting, silverstripe

A live site has suddenly stopped populating with the Page.ss template ( theme/templates/Layout/Page.ss). Pages with custom templates are fine but page page types won't display any data. Therefore there is no log in form for the admin either. No changes have been made to the files. I'm unsure as to what has been changed via the CMS but you can't view the admin form any longer to log in. I've tried replacing the Page.ss file to the original default one, removing extra JS but no luck. I'm stuck as to how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: URL?flush, put it in dev-mode or manually delete cache-files in "./silverstripe-cache" if they are living there. consider log if any?

Comment: Flushing leads to a page stating "too many redirects occurred", its in Dev mode with no errors, can't see a cache folder to delete.

Comment: how if you bypass rewrite, put a index.php in place and access it that way?

Comment: I think your cache folder is not writable. Make sure it is.

Comment: @DanHensby how do I see the cache folder?

Comment: Either create a folder in your webroot called silverstripe-cache and make sure it's writable by the webserver. If it already exists, make sure it's writable.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to create the folder it says the site has run out of disk space!! This could well be the overall problem. I'll report back.

Comment: Still no luck, more space made, added a cache folder, downloaded the site and the database and it acts the same locally. I can't log in, flush or see Layout.ss content. Any more suggestions?

Comment: setup xdebug, set a breakpoint in Page_Controller::init() and see what's happening. Seems your homepage is broken (should have URLSegment "home") and tries to redirect to itself.

Comment: Well, then it may be a syntax problem with your template... Hard to debug without seeing it

Comment: Turns out the space hadn't been updated yet! Its now working. It was a web space issue. Thanks for taking the time to advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting had run out of space. This was causing the described behaviour. Not a SilverStripe issue or site issue but a hosting issue. I'll leave this question / answer up as it may help someone puzzled in the future.